# Make anonymous class static - through static method

Tags: java, android, static, anonymous-class

I have thoughts about the following design

```
public void cntDownPossesion() {

  ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                int poss = Integer.parseInt(possesionTextView.getText().toString());
                poss--;
                possesionTextView.setText("" + poss);
                iCount++;
            }

}
```

Since a new `Runnable()` is created every frame. I use a `SurfaceView` and it uses a workerthread. The `textview` is created on the mainthread so I have to put the updates of "poss" back to the mainthread since the workerthread cannot touch it.

I guess this may create high memory consumtion and do not know if the GC keeps up??

I came with the Idea to make the Runnable-object static but since its an innerclass this is not possible. What about making the context, that is the method `cntDownPossesion` static - if the method is static, isnt the `Innerclass` itself static then???

Comment: Nothing can be made static if `possesionTextView` and `iCount` are instance variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the Runnable to a member variable if you really think it is a performance bottleneck.

```
private Context context;
private TextView possesionTextView;
private int iCount;

private final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int poss = -1 + Integer.parseInt(possesionTextView.getText().toString());
        possesionTextView.setText(String.valueOf(poss));
        iCount++;
    }
};

public void cntDownPossesion() {
  ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(r);
}
```

Comment: good solution, but do you think there is a performance bottleneck in my code? _I could draw the text on a Canvas but using xml-layout is much simpler_

Comment: I don't know - I don't have your code. It is up to you to watch memory usage or UI lag